# "Hand written" recursive descent parser with "catch all" rule

Tags: algorithms, parsing, grammar

I'm trying to write a (scannerless) recursive descent parser with a "catch all" rule for the following "Mustache template" grammar (simplified here):

```
       content : (variable_tag | section_tag | static)*
  variable_tag : mustache_open id mustache_close
   section_tag : mustache_open '#' id mustache_close
                 content mustache_open '/' id mustache_close
 mustache_open : '{{'
mustache_close : '}}'
            id : [a–zA–Z$_][a–zA–Z0–9$_]*
        static : .+  // "catch all"
```

The `static` production would have to stop before the next matched production. And I can't come to a solution for this that would not break the grammar structure.

A valid input is:

```
You have just won {{value}} dollars!
{{#in_ca}}
Well, {{taxed_value}} dollars, after taxes.
{{/in_ca}}
```

The output for that would be an abstract syntactic tree like:

```
                           +-------+
                           |Content|
                           +-------+
                               |
        +---------------+------+--------+--------------+
        |               |               |              | 
+--------------+  +-----------+  +-------------+  +----------+
|Static        |  |VariableTag|  |Static       |  |SectionTag|
|"\nYou...won "|  |value      |  |" dollars"\n"|  |in_ca     |
+--------------+  +-----------+  +-------------+  +----------+
                                                       | 
                                                   +-------+
                                                   |Content|
                                                   +-------+
                                                       |
                                    +-------------+----+--------------+
                                    |             |                   |
                              +----------+  +-----------+  +---------------------+
                              |Static    |  |VariableTag|  |Static               |
                              |"\nWell, "|  |taxed_value|  |" dollars...taxes.\n"|
                              +----------+  +-----------+  +---------------------+
```

Any reference to a implementation of a "catch all" rule for a recursive descent parser?

Comment: I would look to make `static` match `.` not `.*` since `.*` would require arbitrary lookahead to know when to stop.

Comment: Corrected, that should be `.+`

Comment: `.+` suffers from the same problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your grammar will be correct if your catch-all rule only consumes a single character and if you use prioritized choice in the grammar so that `static` is only attempted as a last resort. Of course, these single-character tokens are terribly inefficient. There are two ways to fix this:

- let the catch-all rule be `static : [^\{]+ | .`
- have your parser store a pointer to the previous token. If you are reading a static token and the previous token was static, then append the string rather than creating a new item in your AST. This can actually be a bit tricky to pull off, since in a RecDesc parser each rule would usually fail or return an AST subtree. It might make sense to introduce a pseudo-token signifying “success, but no action needes” since the token would already reside in the AST in case of a fixup and should not be added two times.

There is a problem with this: since at no point do you commit to one alternative, this parser involves a lot of backtracking. I would expect this to cause exponential complexity, unless you use a Packrat strategy (or use a parsing technique that is actually suited for ambiguous grammars). Here's an example input for such behaviour:

```
{{#foo}} {{#a}} {{#a}} {{#a}} {{/foo} sic!
```

According to your grammar, this input would be completely static, but the parser would recurse four times into the section rule.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular grammar, I think you can just match until you see `{{`. Then push `{{` back on the tokens to be read.

So I think the key here is just having the ability to push back onto the token list. Having a fixed buffer of tokens is generally good for error handling too, in LR parsers, but I wouldn't be surprised if it is useful in LL parsers as well.

Comment: That doesn't work as the grammar is defined, consider `abc{{123` - that should match `static`.

Comment: And that's true. But it does seem like the easiest way to solve this is probably some form of tokenization at the expense of the pretty grammar. I think tokenization can likely be done efficiently and then make matching something not too far off from the original grammar much easier. How would you approach it?